# How do I extract a square root in a field of p-adic numbers?

Tags: rational-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

Retrieval of square root in the field of p-adic numbers.

1. Find ${\sqrt 5}$ in field $\Bbb {Q_{11}}$
2. Find ${\sqrt 3}$ in field $\Bbb {Q_{13}}$

Any information that will help solve this task will be useful.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88488/square-roots-in-the-p-adics)

Comment: Your question doesn’t seem to me to be exactly what the linked question was asking. You seem to be asking how to do something as a construction. I mean, how to actually get a $p$-adic expansion of these square roots. That is what the “task” you quoted seems to demand.

Comment: @Lubin:  you should consider answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664217/example-of-a-local-ring-which-is-not-an-integral-domain)

Comment: All right @J.W.Tanner: after my post-breakfast nap.

Comment: Whoops, closed questions can’t be answered. I voted to reopen, but I doubt that anything will result.

Comment: I actually meant [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664217/example-of-a-local-ring-which-is-not-an-integral-domain) (click the blue words to see the one I mean), though an answer was given meanwhile