# Example of a local ring which is not an integral domain

Tags: ring-theory

Ring of integers is an integral domain which is not a local ring.
Ring of p adic numbers is a local ring which is also an integral domain.
Are there any example of a local ring which is not an integral domain?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about $10$-adic numbers?

Comment: $\mathbf Z/p^k\mathbf Z$, where $p$ is prime and $k\ge 2$, is such an example

Comment: To add a geometric example to the already mentioned arithmetic ones: $\mathbb C[x]/(x^2) $

Comment: Thank you good examples, I want more detail about ' 10 adic numbers'. If you are Ok, I'd be appreciated if you answer with 10 adic numbers in answer form.

Comment: I'd suggest you read [this](http://www.numericana.com/answer/p-adic.htm#composite-radix)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Aren't the $10-$adics the direct sum of $2-$ and $5-$ adics? Then it would certainly not be local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.

In general, $R/M^n$ where $M$ is a maximal ideal and $R$ is commutative will be an example, as long as $M\neq \{0\}$.

Comment: This [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=23&L=8) returns 10 examples at present, and I think at least half are not of the form I'm describing in this solution.

Comment: What does M^n mean

Comment: @pHotone the n-fold ideal product of M.  That is, the set of all finite sums of n-fold products of elements of M.