# Legendre symbol on $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I have seen that you can define the usual modular arithmetic on the $p$-adic integers:
For $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ and a prime $p$,
$$a\equiv b\pmod{p}\iff (a-b)/p\in \mathbb{Z}_p.$$

My question is, can we also define the Legendre symbol of $p$-adic integers?

For example, for a prime $p$ and $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p$, define
$$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = \begin{cases} 1\quad\text{if $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ has a solution $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$} \\
-1\quad\text{if $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ has no solution $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$}\\
0\quad\text{if $a\equiv0\pmod{p}$}\end{cases}.$$

Can I use the usual properties of the Legendre symbol in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Square roots in the $p$-adics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88488/square-roots-in-the-p-adics)

Comment: @AnneBauval, I believe the link asks which integers are square roots in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. I was asking about the use of the usual Legendre symbol on $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and not $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Can I assume the usual properties of Legendre symbol in this case?

Comment: I did not think much about it but I believe [Bruno Joyal's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88491/386889) answers your post.

Comment: @AnneBauval The value of $a$ (in the link, it's $n$) they were talking about is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$. In my question, $a\in \mathbb{Z}_p$. That alone, makes a difference between my question and the answer of Joyal.

Comment: The answers don't assume that it is in $\Bbb{Z}$. For $p\ne 2$ on $\Bbb{Z}_p^\times$ the Legendre symbol is the same as on $\Bbb{F}_p^\times$, but on $p \Bbb{Z}_p$ it needs to take in account if the valuation is even and the image in $\Bbb{Q}_p^\times/p^\Bbb{Z}$ which makes it non-continuous (for the $p$-adic topology).

Comment: What if I assume $v_p(a)=0$, and define $$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = \begin{cases} 1\quad\text{if $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ has a solution $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$} \\
-1\quad\text{if $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ has no solution $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$}.\end{cases}.$$

Is the problem already fixed?

Comment: I have added "p-adic integers" in your title in order to avoid confusion with the "ordinary" integers modulo $p$.